# Using Delphi 7 to get HTML, I get an annoying zero at the end

Tags: delphi-7

Using Delphi 7 to get HTML from HTTPS, no matter what URL I use, I always get a zero after the end `</html>`, like this: `"...</html>0"`.

Let's say I call this:

```
memo1.text := GetUrlContent('http://google.com');
```

I get all the HTML and then a zero:

```
[],"sbpl":24,"sbpr":24,"scd":10,"sce":5,"stok":"Y2aF9aDK2ABWRqkd17qwTWg63TY"},"d":{},"ZI/YVQ":{},"Qnk92g":{},"U5B21g":{},"DPBNMg":{},"YFCs/g":{}};google.x(null,function(){});(function(){var r=[];google.plm(r);})();(function(){var m=[]
;google.jsc && google.jsc.m(m);})();</script></div></body></html>
0
```

This zero, did you see that??

Here is the function I'm using:

```
function GetUrlContent(const Url: string): string;
var
  NetHandle: HINTERNET;
  UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1024] of Char;
  BytesRead: dWord;
begin
  Result := '';
  NetHandle := InternetOpen('Delphi 5.x', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);

  if Assigned(NetHandle) then 
  begin
    UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

    if Assigned(UrlHandle) then
      { UrlHandle valid? Proceed with download }
    begin
      FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
      repeat
        Result := Result + Buffer;
        FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
        InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead);
      until BytesRead = 0;
      InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
    end
    else
      { UrlHandle is not valid. Raise an exception. }
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot open URL %s', [Url]);

    InternetCloseHandle(NetHandle);
  end
  else
    { NetHandle is not valid. Raise an exception }
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to initialize Wininet');
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not handling  `InternetReadFile()` correctly:

- you are appending your `Buffer` to your `Result` before you have even called `InternetReadFile()` for the first time.
- you are not doing any error checking on the actual call to `InternetReadFile()`.
- you are assuming that `InternetReadFile()` returns null-terminated data, but it doesn't. You must take `BytesRead` into account when appending your `Buffer` to `Result`, otherwise you risk appending garbage beyond `BytesRead` number of bytes.

Also, if `InternetOpenUrl()` fails, you leak the handle returned by `InternetOpen()`.

Try this instead:

```
function GetUrlContent(const Url: string): string;
var
  NetHandle: HINTERNET;
  UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1024] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
  Size: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  NetHandle := InternetOpen('Delphi 5.x', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if not Assigned(NetHandle) then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to initialize Wininet');
  try
    UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    if not Assigned(UrlHandle) then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot open URL %s', [Url]);
    try
      { Proceed with download }
      Size := 0;
      repeat
        if not InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead) then
          raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot download from URL %s', [Url]);
        if BytesRead = 0 then Break;
        SetLength(Result, Size + BytesRead);
        Move(Buffer, Result[Size + 1], BytesRead);
        Inc(Size, BytesRead);
      until False;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(NetHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function GetUrlContent(const Url: string): string;
var
  NetHandle: HINTERNET;
  UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1024] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
  Data: TStringStream;
begin
  Result := '';
  NetHandle := InternetOpen('Delphi 5.x', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if not Assigned(NetHandle) then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to initialize Wininet');
  try
    UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    if not Assigned(UrlHandle) then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot open URL %s', [Url]);
    try
      { Proceed with download }
      Data := TStringStream.Create;
      try
        repeat
          if not InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead) then
            raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot download from URL %s', [Url]);
          if BytesRead = 0 then Break;
          Data.WriteBuffer(Buffer, BytesRead);
        until False;
        Result := Data.DataString;
      finally
        Data.Free;
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(NetHandle);
  end;
end;
```